# PHP Email Form (BCC Recipient)

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm using an array for an email form, and I want to BCC a recipient for some of the options.

The code below appears to hide **hidden@test.com** when the form is opened from Yahoo Mail.  However, when it is opened from a client like SquirrelMail, the hidden email address is shown!

Is there an optimal way to hide email addresses in a similar format to the one below? Looking for something simple; if it's too difficult I won't stress about it.

```
array("0",""),
array("1","test@test.com,BCC:hidden@test.com","test@test.com","test@test.com"),
array("2","test@test.com","test@test.com","test@test.com"),
array("3","test@test.com","test@test.com","test@test.com")
```

Comment: How are you sending the mail?. Show your code

Comment: I'm using a custom script and everything works fine, but I'm just wondering if I have the correct formatting above for BCC.